# Is it legal for a US citizen to purchase foreign war bonds?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

I'm a US citizen considering buying Ukrainian war bonds, but I'm not sure if there would be legal or unusual tax repercussions?

Also interested in the general legality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring specific sanctions, it’s generally legal to own foreign bonds.

Comment: The interest upon which would be taxable income to the U.S. citizen buying them.

Comment: @ohwilleke and the write-off will be tax deductible when Ukraine collapses

Comment: If you itemize.